# Framer Motion: Fix child distortion when animated with AnimateSharedLayout

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

#### I want to crossfade a card (div with children) with AnimateSharedLayout when it gets expanded.

##### However, the font gets distorted on the layout animation.

##### [Here is a link to a codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-projects-with-animatesharedlayout-vgm2b)

Here is my code (I am using Tailwind CSS):

This is the `Projects` component that holds all the cards in a CSS grid:

```
export default function Projects() {
  const projectObjArray = [
    {
      title: "Project 1",
      description: "some description",
      background: "#f00",
      link: ""
    },
    {
      title: "Project 2",
      description: "some description",
      background: "#f00",
      link: ""
    },
    {
      title: "Project 3",
      description: "some description",
      background: "#f00",
      link: ""
    }
  ];

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-6xl mb-5 md:text-left md:ml-10 pb-5">My Projects</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-10">
        {projectObjArray.map((el, index) => {
          if (index !== expanded) {
            return (
              <ProjectTemplate
                projectobj={el}
                key={el.title}
                index={index}
                setexpanded={setExpanded}
              />
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <ProjectTemplateExpanded
                projectobj={el}
                key={el.title}
                index={index}
                setexpanded={setExpanded}
              />
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When a card is clicked, its index gets saved in the `expanded` state.
Then, the `ProjectTemplateExpanded` component will render at that position instead of the `ProjectTemplate`.

Here are these components:

```
export default function ProjectTemplate(props) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ borderRadius: "100px" }}
      animate={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
      className="w-full h-56 flex flex-col justify-center"
      style={{ background: props.projectobj.background }}
      onClick={() => {
        props.setexpanded(props.index);
      }}
      layoutId={`Container${props.projectobj.title}`}
      transition={{ duration: 2 }}
    >
      <motion.h1
        layoutId={`Title${props.projectobj.title}`}
        // layout
        transition={{ duration: 2 }}
        className="text-2xl"
      >
        {props.projectobj.title}
      </motion.h1>
      <motion.p
        layoutId={`Description${props.projectobj.title}`}
        // layout
        transition={{ duration: 2 }}
        className="text-1xl"
      >
        {props.projectobj.description}
      </motion.p>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ProjectTemplateExpanded(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-56"></div>
      <motion.div
        className="w-full fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-50 flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
        style={{ background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" }}
        onClick={() => {
          props.setexpanded(undefined);
        }}
      >
        <motion.div
          layoutId={`Container${props.projectobj.title}`}
          transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          initial={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
          animate={{ borderRadius: "100px" }}
          style={{
            background: props.projectobj.background,
            width: "80vw",
            height: "50vh"
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
          className="flex flex-col justify-center"
        >
          <motion.h1
            layoutId={`Title${props.projectobj.title}`}
            // layout
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            className="text-2xl"
          >
            {props.projectobj.title}
          </motion.h1>
          <motion.p
            layoutId={`Description${props.projectobj.title}`}
            // layout
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            className="text-1xl"
          >
            {props.projectobj.description}
          </motion.p>
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The Projects component is wrapped with an `AnimateSharedLayout`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App text-white pt-5 px-5">
      <AnimateSharedLayout type="crossfade">
        <Projects />
      </AnimateSharedLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.framer.com/docs/component/##layout-animation) states:

> To correct distortion on immediate children, add layout to those too.

So I've tried adding the layout prop beside the layoutId on the h1 and the p tag, but that didn't change anything.

[This blog post](https://www.framer.com/blog/posts/magic-motion/) states that scale correction gets applied on any component that takes part in a shared element transition (that's the case here, because of the layoutId set on the children)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put `items-center` on the container. Then, the width of the `h1` and `p` elements will get corrected during the animation.

Comment: You should accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I still need to wait 1 hour to do this.

Comment: `items-center`, `items-start` or `items-end` depending on the alignment you use

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the value passed to the layout property to "position".  This way the text keeps the same style.  I also move the height and width styling from the style property to the animate property in the ProjectTemplateExpanded function for a smoother animation.  I used the The @keyframes Rule information from W3Schools as a guide.  Try the following:

```
export default function ProjectTemplate(props) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ borderRadius: "100px" }}
      animate={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
      className="w-full h-56 flex flex-col justify-center"
      style={{ background: props.projectobj.background }}
      onClick={() => {
        props.setexpanded(props.index);
      }}
      layoutId={`Container${props.projectobj.title}`}
      transition={{ duration: 2 }}
    >
      <motion.h1
        layoutId={`Title${props.projectobj.title}`}
        layout="position"
        transition={{ duration: 2 }}
        className="text-2xl"
      >
        {props.projectobj.title}
      </motion.h1>
      <motion.p
        layoutId={`Description${props.projectobj.title}`}
        layout="position"
        transition={{ duration: 2 }}
        className="text-1xl"
      >
        {props.projectobj.description}
      </motion.p>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export default function ProjectTemplateExpanded(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-56"></div>
      <motion.div
        className="w-full fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-50 flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
        style={{ background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" }}
        onClick={() => {
          props.setexpanded(undefined);
        }}
      >
        <motion.div
          layoutId={`Container${props.projectobj.title}`}
          transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          initial={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
          animate={{ borderRadius: "100px",
            width: "80vw",
            height: "50vh" }}
          style={{
            background: props.projectobj.background,
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
          className="flex flex-col justify-center"
        >
          <motion.h1
            layoutId={`Title${props.projectobj.title}`}
            layout="position"
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            className="text-2xl"
          >
            {props.projectobj.title}
          </motion.h1>
          <motion.p
            layoutId={`Description${props.projectobj.title}`}
            layout="position"
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            className="text-1xl"
          >
            {props.projectobj.description}
          </motion.p>
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
}
```

References:

The @keyframes Rule - CSS Animations.  W3Schools. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp. (Accessed 24 August, 2021).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Try it out: [I've included your changes in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-projects-with-animatesharedlayout-forked-layout-true-2n76n?file=/src/ProjectTemplateExpanded.js)
Did it work for you? Any clue why it's not working?

Comment: @dasJulian I've updated the answer.  The only was giving the layout property a value of "position" instead.

Comment: This fixes the text distortion, but now the text jumps around because the height and width don't get animated. 
[Try it here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-projects-with-animatesharedlayout-forked-layout-position-q8u9c?file=/src/ProjectTemplateExpanded.js)
There must be a better solution for this because they made [something similar for the framer website.](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animatesharedlayout-app-store-demo-i1kct?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js)
I don't know what they did differently.

Comment: @dasJulian I've updated the answer.  The only change was moving the width and height styling to the animate property of the ProjectTemplateExpanded function.

Comment: I've played around with your solution - but I could only get the outslide animation to work. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-projects-with-animatesharedlayout-partly-fixed-l8ccv) The font still jumps crazily around and the border-radius seems to be buggy.

Comment: Someone on discord gave me the answer, I posted it as community-wiki.